# Accessing autocomplete list from the browser for a search box

Tags: javascript, browser, autocomplete

I have a text box on a webpage where users are allowed to type in texts to search.
I have a dropdown-menu in place which displays few suggestions the users to search. 
The text box has the autocomplete attribute set to off. Reason is the browser's autocomplete drop down conflicted with the drop down that I had created.
The browser's autocomplete setup used to suggest to the user what teh user had previously searched.

Now that I have turned autocomplete off and have a custom drop down with suggestions, I want to access the list of terms that the browser stored to display its own autocomplete.

Basically I want to add those previously searched terms in my custom drop down along with my suggestions.
Can someone let me know how I can access the list of terms that the browser suggests as previously searched terms when autocomplete is turned on

My code is as below

```
<form method="get" action="${ctx.contextPath}/search" autocomplete="off"
  class="search-form">
<input id="searchField" type="text" class="search-field" name="dq"
       placeholder="${content.placeholder!}"
       onclick=showSearchTerms();
       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/>
<ul id="popularSearchListDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="searchField">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Most Common Search Terms</li>
    [#list popularSearchTerms as term]
        <li class="dropdown-item">
            <a href="${ctx.contextPath}/search?q=${term}">${term}</a>
        </li>
    [/#list]
</ul>
<button id="search-go" class="submit-search" type="submit">
[#include "/images/icon-search.png"]
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The list that the browser stored and display is depend by each user. You also can disable/enable this by enter to browser settings. In other words - if the user disable it on his system it's not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone let me know how I can access the list of terms that the browser suggests as previously searched terms when autocomplete is turned on

Not possible. It would be a pretty big security hole for scripts to have access the user's autocomplete field history.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nirmalya Guha Khasnobis,

You could try a dependency "ui-select".
https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/

Example: HTML

```
  <ui-select theme="bootstrap" class="inputColor" name="customer" ng-model="customer">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Customer...">{{$select.selected.fullName}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="customer in customerList | filter: $select.search">
          <div ng-bind-html="customer.fullName | highlight: $select.search"></div>

        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```

Example: JS

```
   $scope.customerList = [{id: 1, fullName: "CUSTOMER1"}, 
{id:2, fullName: "CUSTOMER2"},{id:3, fullName: "CUSTOMER3"}];
```